# Change Text in jquery mobile Loading Dialog while displayed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I show and hide my jq mobile loading dialogs manually. I prefer this. My question when I show the jq mobile loading dialog is it possible to change the text in it while it is already displayed?

For instance when it comes up I have it say "loading your data". What I want to do is change it to "data loading finished" at a certain point before I hide it.

Comment: Of course you can. You just bind to the event that triggers the change and with the appropriate selector to the content of the dialog you change the text via text() or html() methods. If you want paste some code of what you've already achieved (better to be in jsfiddle).

Comment: Are you using ajax for the "loading your data" part? It's pretty simple if that's the case

Comment: I think I get the fact that I can change the text. What I can't figure out is what I change. What is the div that the text is in so I can change the text or html?

Comment: I got it. It is ui-loader. Seeing as how alkis really answered it with the text() method, please create your answer so I can give you credit. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, although you did by yourself. But I will gladly take the points :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. You just bind to the event that triggers the change and with the appropriate selector to the content of the dialog you change (in this case .ui-loader) the text via text() or html() methods.